# Finite alternating series with edge condition?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't have much in the way of a formal mathematics background, so please forgive my limited math vocabulary (and lack of LaTEX abilities).

So say I've got a series of length `n+1` where the first `n` terms look like: `a+b+a+b+a...`

Term `n+1` is equal to whatever would naturally follow if the pattern would continue, but multiplied by `1/2`

For example, a series of length 5 would look like: `a+b+a+b+(1/2*a)`

How can I represent this mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
\begin{align*}
S_{n} & =\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{n}{2}\left(a+b\right) & \text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\frac{1}{2}b+\left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil a+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor b & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
You can simplify this further.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.